# TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox gradient colors in borders

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

In my application I am using TextInputLayout with an updated material theme `style=Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`.

I have to add a gradient colors to the borders of each TextInputLayout (from blue to green), like the next image.

[image]

The problem is that I do not find any solution of how to implement a gradient color effect for borders. I am able to change the color of borders but is a color solid one, like next gif:

[image]

This is how I create a TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Label"
                style="@style/MyTextInputEditText"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

styles:

```
 <style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/edit_text_box_border</item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyTextInputEditText" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorCharcoalGrey</item>
    </style>
```

edit_text_box_border.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorBlue" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorBlue" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorBlue" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorBlue"/>
</selector>
```

**Is it possible to add a gradient effect to a TextInputLayout with an updated material theme?**

**If is so, How can I do it?**

*Thank in advance. Any help/suggest will be appreciate.*

Comment: Nope, `TextInputLayout` doesn't support that, as is. Each state color of that outline stroke is set with a plain old simple color value. The underlying `MaterialShapeDrawable` _might_ be able to do gradients (not sure; haven't checked), but `TextInputLayout` only ever hands it simple color values.

Comment: Nani! Well, bad news for my design team. Thanks